# CSS: Why does margin-top affect floated neighbor?

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

I have a div floating to the left of two text input elements. When I set margin-top on the inputs, the margin of the floating div is affected as well. Why is this, and how the F can I stop it from happening?!

Relevant HTML:

```
<body>
    <div class="manage-page">
        <h2>Set Logo Order</h2>
        <hr>
        <div class="logo-container">
            <div class="logo-draggable">
                <div class="logo-image-box"></div>
                <input type="text" />
                <input type="text" />
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
```

Relevant CSS:

```
.manage-page {
    margin-top: 2.5em;
    margin-left: 25%;
    margin-right: 25%;
    min-width: 50%;
}

.logo-container {
    border:1px solid #777777;
    clear: left;
    cursor: move;
    height: 12.5%;
    margin-bottom: 0.625em;
}

.logo-image-box {
    background-position: 50% 50%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-size: contain;
    border:1px solid #000000;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0 .875em;
    width: 12.5%;
}

.logo-draggable input {
    border: 1px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius: 0.25em;
    display: block;
    font-size: 0.875em;
    height: 2em;
    line-height: 1.25;
    margin-top: .5em;
    padding: 0.375em 0.75em;
    outline: none;
}
```

You can see it in action at the jsfiddle URL below. Just change the margin-top of `.logo-draggable input` and watch as the `.logo-image-box` gets bumped up/down as well:

http://jsfiddle.net/Uj2K6/

Answer (score 4):

I think you suffer from [collapsing margins](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/m/margin/) (scroll down).

> Vertical margins on different elements that touch each other (thus
>   have no content, padding, or borders separating them) will collapse,
>   forming a single margin that is equal to the greater of the adjoining
>   margins.

Comment: Collapsing margins have to do with the space below and above two elements when margin-bottom and margin-top are set on them. That's not my problem.

Comment: Well, you are the expert. ;-) I don't no squat about CSS, but I *do* trust the guys at css-tricks.com and their definition (which I politely pasted above) seems to be slightly different than yours.

Comment: This answer seems to be true. The CSS spec says that 'When the float occurs between two collapsing margins, the float is positioned as if it had an otherwise empty anonymous block parent taking part in the flow. The position of such a parent is defined by the rules in the section on margin collapsing' (http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-position). This seems to be exactly the case here.

Comment: @GolezTrol The definition of collapsing margins given at the link you referenced is just what I said: "_Vertical_ margins on different elements that touch each other (thus have no content, padding, or borders separating them) will collapse, forming a single margin that is equal to the greater of the adjoining margins. This does not happen on horizontal margins (left and right), _only vertical (top and bottom_)." Moreover, the page you linked mentions nothing about how to solve my float issue. Nevertheless, as the link provided by Ilya points out, you were on the right track. Thank you both.

Comment: Maybe I completely missed the point, but I thought your question was about vertical margins (top, to be precise). The fact that the elements are floated next to each other horizontally doesn't make the margins horizontal margins. But I agree, the link @IlyaStreltsyn specified is more informative than mine.